# When hold pressed ui canvas button on mouse down do something when released do something

Tags: c#, canvas, unity-game-engine

```
public void application()    // function when the mouse only find the ui canvas button 
{
    // when the mouse find only canvas button and when clicked then do something else stop

    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
    {
        print("button pressed");
    }
    else {
        print("button released");
    }
}
```

Comment: GetbuttonDown and getbutton up instead of getbutton should work

Comment: does not work that their return type is totally changed...

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with the UI system, you should use the IPointerXXXX interfaces:

```
public class MyClass: MonoBehaviour, IPointerUpHandler{

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```